# Dynamically switch control type to show different content types

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my app (windows 8.1) I use the split Visual Studio template. It is working and I can show text content if I choose an item.

The content is mixed with text, images, pdfs.

**So how can I dynamically switch the control type (eg TextBlock, Image, UserControl) based an the content data?**

If I get text it should displayed in an TextBlock, but if I get an Image (Link) it should displayed in a image control. (Maybe the way to switch the control type is wrong, I don't know!?)

**Can I solve this in XAML or should I do it in code behind?**

I don't know how can I do this. Can anyone please give me a hint?

```
<Grid x:Name="itemDetailGrid" Margin="0,60,0,50">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,20,0" Width="180" Height="180" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
            <StackPanel x:Name="itemDetailTitlePanel" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBlock x:Name="itemTitle" Margin="0,-10,0,0" Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="itemSubtitle" Margin="0,0,0,20" Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
          <!--  <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,20,0,0" Text="{Binding Content}" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/> -->
            <Image Source="{Binding Content}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,20,0,0"  Stretch="UniformToFill" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is for you to use `DataTemplate`s to define how each data type should be rendered in the UI. All you need to do is to declare a `DataTemplate` for each different data type:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:String}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
</DataTemplate>
...
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Custom:DataObject}">
    <UserControl DataContext="{Binding}">
</DataTemplate>
```

If you omit the `x:Key` references (as in the example above), then the Framework will automatically render the content of the relevant `DataTemplate` whenever it comes across one of the specified data types. Please see the [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN for further details.

Comment: hmmm... I think the OP is using WinRT and there's no `{x:Type}` in WinRT.

Comment: Ahhh... I was wondering what a 'split Visual Studio template' was.

Comment: oh sry, yes I'm using WinRT. Maybe this is also possible with `DataTemplateSelector`. But my content type is always string. If I get an image or an pdf I get only the link. So how can I devide which `DataTemplate`to use to display it in my app?

Comment: Well that's what happens when you don't provide all the relevant information in your question... you get invalid answer(s). You won't be able to use a `DataTemplateSelector` if all your data types are `string`... how would you differentiate between them? You'd need to use objects of actual different types to do that.

Comment: I get the data from SharePoint. I can differentiate by file extension if it is a link or/and I set a additional flag in the mapping list.

Comment: In WPF, it is *always* worth putting your data into the right 'shape' for display. In your case, if you can tell which `string` is supposed to be which data type, then just regenerate the values in the actual data types that they're supposed to be at the data access stage.